# Advanced persmissions handling in CDK: passRole, creating instances & passing multiple permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I have a really nasty IAM / permissions question for CDK. I've already gotten this to work on the console. This is a question in 2 parts, the first dealing with what I've already done, and the second part looking at how it can be replicated in CDK.

### *Existing Solution*

I have a Lambda Function which has can be triggered from a number of sources. Each source provides some parameters that govern execution. The lambda's main task is to create an EC2 instance and send it a user data script to execute. The virtual machine queues up a spot instance to save some money and when it finishes, it terminates. It's a fairly hefty virtual machine as it needs to do some pretty heavy data crunching, but very infrequently, hence why I don't just leave it alive all the time.

The virtual machine itself requires priveldeges to fire off SES emails, and access s3 buckets for both read and write.

[image]

### *Permissions*

The Lambda has 3 policy documents in it's role:

1. basic execution.
2. EC2 Full Access AWS Managed policy.
3. A custom Pass-Role policy, below:

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "iam:PassRole",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/EC2Role-Machine"
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "iam:CreateInstanceProfile",
                    "iam:AddRoleToInstanceProfile"
                ],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

The pass-role policy contains the following permissions:

- to create '*' instance within my account.
- to add role to '*' instance within my account.
- to pass Role (EC2-Custom-Role)

### *EC2 Custom Role*

This EC2 custom role contains 2 policies

- SES Full Access
- s3 Access for about 8 different actions 's3:xxxxx' for 4 separate bucket resources. See below. N.B. "s3:*" crept in during a moment of weakness when things were refusing to work - some head-scratching required as to why this is necessary.

```
     {
       "Version":"2012-10-17",
       "Statement":[
          {
             "Sid":"VisualEditor0",
             "Effect":"Allow",
             "Action":[
                "s3:GetAccessPoint",
                "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:ListAccessPoints",
                "s3:ListJobs",
                "s3:CreateJob"
             ],
             "Resource":"*"
          },
          {
             "Sid":"VisualEditor1",
             "Effect":"Allow",
             "Action":[
                "s3:*",
                "s3:ListObjectsV2"
             ],
             "Resource":[
                "arn:aws:s3:::monkey.test.bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::reports.monkeytronics.co.nz/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::analytics.monkeytronics.co.nz/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::analytics.monkeytronics.co.nz"
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
```

### *Question 1*

While this works... Is it right? Are there any security or best practice improvements that should be made?

### *Question 2*

How can this be replicated in CDK. I have started to work on it, but rapidly hit a wall. The error appears when the lambda is triggered. The main guts of the Lambda are as follows. Basically, its just spinning up a new EC2 instance and shoving in the user data. On completion, the EC2 terminates. The secuity group, role & key are all preprepared, and I know they work fine from before.

```
// my custom AMI
    var instanceParams = {
        ImageId: 'ami-0dfxxxxxxxxxxxe', 
        InstanceType: 't2.xlarge',
        KeyName: 'EC2-Test-Key-Pair',
        MinCount: 1,
        MaxCount: 1,
        SecurityGroups: ['launch-wizard-1'],
        UserData: userDataEncoded,
        InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior: "terminate",
        // InstanceMarketOptions: {
        //     "MarketType" : "spot",
        //     //"SpotOptions" : SpotOptions // max price / block period etc...
        // },
        IamInstanceProfile : { 
            "Arn" : "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxx:instance-profile/EC2Role-R-Machine"
        }
    };
    
// Create a promise on an EC2 service object
    var instancePromise = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'}).runInstances(instanceParams).promise();    
    
// Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
    await instancePromise.then(
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var instanceId = data.Instances[0].InstanceId;
            console.log("Created instance", instanceId);
        }
    );
```

Here is the error message from cloudwatch. Not hugely helpful I'm afraid, but enough to tell that it's in the permissions. In spite of having successfully implemented this in the console, I can't say I really have a firm grasp on the use of pass role & other permission concepts here.

> "errorType": "UnauthorizedOperation",
> "errorMessage": "You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: OhVTfR8eBb7y.....

PS Thanks for sorting out my messed up code formatting!

Comment: " started to work on it, but rapidly hit a wall" is not specific. I think you could make a dedicated question for that, with your CDK code, exact error messages if any, or explanation why this code does not work as expected.

Comment: posted extra details on lambda & error message.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to question 2 looks like this:

For the Dynamic EC2 object:

```
// create ec2 role & add policies.
      const ec2RoleR = new iam.Role(this, 'ec2RoleR', {
            assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('ec2.amazonaws.com'),
            description: 'EC2 Role - SES & s3 access.',
            roleName: 'sn-v1-EC2-Role-R'
      });

      ec2RoleR.addToPolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
            resources: [
                  s3Reports.bucketArn,
                  s3Analytics.bucketArn
            ],
            actions: [
                   's3:GetAccessPoint',
                   's3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock',
                   's3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock',
                   's3:ListAllMyBuckets',
                   's3:ListAccessPoints',
                   's3:ListJobs',
                   's3:CreateJob'
            ],
      }));

  ec2RoleR.addManagedPolicy(iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AmazonSESFullAccess'));
```

For the Lambda:

```
// Add necessary policies to Lambda
      lambdaReportPutR.addToRolePolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({ // needs SES & iotPublish permissions!
            effect: Effect.ALLOW,
            resources: [
                  "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/EC2Role-R-Machine", // console role.
                  ec2RoleR.roleArn // cdk role above
            ],
            actions: ['iam:PassRole'],
      })); 
      
      // create & add role to * instance
      lambdaReportPutR.addToRolePolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
            effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            resources: ['arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:*'],
            actions: [
                  "iam:CreateInstanceProfile",
                  "iam:AddRoleToInstanceProfile"
            ]
      }));

      // ec2 full access by lambda.
      lambdaReportPutR.role?.addManagedPolicy(iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AmazonEC2FullAccess'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Q1.

You write "about 8 different actions 's3:xxxxx' ", but your policy allows for **all possible S3 actions**, not only 8, due to `s3:*` in:

```
             "Action":[
                "s3:*",
                "s3:ListObjectsV2"
             ],
```

This includes **deletion** of your objects and buckets.

Comment: Its a work in progress still, with test resources! Great point though. I need to be stricter with the exact permissions.

Comment: @monkey I also wonder that since you have multiple buckets, maybe it would be easier to control access to them from your role, through bucket policies. This would simplify your role, and delegate bucket access permissions management to the respective buckets, rather then putting everything under one role.

Comment: True. Using bucket policies is a nice idea.  Less clutter. One downside that they would have to be very general, as the ec2 resource is dynamically created and destroyed, so it would need to be something like ec2:*. I'm going to offer an answer to Q2, and see if there are any advances on what I come up with.